# How can I set the maximum current in my CircuitLab circuit?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, electromagnetic, circuitlab

I have designed a circuit for two electromagnets to be turned on and off by a Raspberry Pi, but the total current draw by the circuit is 10.99A and my power pack has a limit of 2A. How can I simulate this current limit so I can calculate the required resistance of Resistor R2 to achieve a voltage of 6V across Electromagnet 1?

Here's the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fel151.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks!

Comment: I have double checked - 2A is the value at which it will safely limit the current.

Comment: The current through EM2 will be smaller than the current in EM1 if there is 6V across EM1. Therefore, the current through the FET will be approximately that through EM1. Thus, for there to be 6V across EM1, you want the resistance of the FET + R2 to be approximately that of EM1 or 10.5 Ohms.

Comment: Your approach is a bit backward.  You don't need to limit your supply to do what you want -- you design your circuit to not draw more than 2 amps (I'd probably opt for some headroom there, like 1.75 Amps or less)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be careful here. "... my power pack has a limit of 2A." What happens when you try to draw more current? Will it shut down politely or will it go on fire? Is 2 A the rated maximum (and you have to make sure you don't exceed it) or is it the value at which it will safely limit the current (and you don't have to worry)?

You have two loads:

- 10.5 Ω: \$ I = \frac V R = \frac {12}{10.5} = 1.2 \ \text A \$ roughly. (Batteries aren't precision devices.)
- 120 Ω:  \$ I = \frac V R = \frac {12}{120} = 0.1\ \text A \$
- \$Total\ load = 1.2 + 0.1 = 1.3 A\$.

You're safe.

---

> ... but how come, if you open the circuit in CircuitLab and hover with your cursor over R2 or the battery, it says 10.9A, not 1.2A? Why would this be?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI58kx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Test circuit.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Simulation results.*

Steps to reproduce:

- Connect a 3.3 V source to drive the MOSFET.
- Double click the MOSFET and change the V_TO (turn-on voltage) to 2.0 V. I didn't look up the V<sub>TO</sub> for the IRF530 so you need to check that it's suitable for 3.3 V logic.
- Then check the currents. I'm getting 1.067 A which is about right as you have two resistances in series with EM1: R2 and the resistance of MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I'm missing something here, but how come, if you open the circuit in CircuitLab and hover with your cursor over R2 or the battery, it says 10.9A, not 1.2A? Why would this be?

Comment: I don't know how you're getting that. See the update.

Comment: Ahh! That makes sense now! Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because EM1 and EM2 are using two different symbols - a lamp and a coil.

A lamp has a VERY low resistance when off, but as it warms up, it's resistance increases dramatically.

A coil has a constant resistance, regardless of elapsed time. (It also acquires stored energy in the form of a magnetic field, requiring the use of the "Flyback Diode" for when it shuts off.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. EM2 is also a lamp, I just accidentally used the curly lamp notation instead of the conventional notation